# ios7 UILabel + Helvetica Neue ultralight Ailiasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, ios7

I am just making some finishing touches to my app for an iOS7 release.

In line with Apples new guidelines, I have changed my font throughout the app, mainly in UILables to Helvetica Neue Ultralight, using attributed text.

A lot of my label views have transparent backgrounds, and the text within is white. There is terrible ailiasing occurring, and in some cases it is making my text illegible.

Is there any form of anti-ailiasing I can apply via the ios SDK?

I am testing this on an iPad mini so it is not retina. I will not be able to test this on a retina device for 2-3 days.

When I attempt to make a screenshot, the text appears perfectly anti-ailiased.

Thanks for your time

Comment: It's hard to answer the question in its current form.  Can you provide  code or context?  Are you only experiencing issue on non-retina devices?  Can you provide screenshots of the issue?

Comment: @BrianNickel Hi, the attributes are set via IB not programatically. I just attempted a screenshot of the issue, unfortunately it appears anit-ailiased in the screenshot itself! I have edited the question with a few updates.

Comment: This is precisely the issue described in box at the top of the [CALayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).   It's probably made obvious by an ultra-light font.

Essentially, the issue is that iOS can't oversample and the low=--pass filter the rendered text when it doesn't know the background that will be behind it.   If it doesn't change, you could always capture the background beneath it and then render on top.

Comment: Thanks @marko, never thought of checking that reference. I will code my solution tomorrow and provide it as an answer.